# getline vs cin giving different o/p

Tags: c++

Have a look at this code.
The issue the mention below.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
string str;

getline(cin,str);//PROBLEM LINE let this line be (a)
cout<<str;
}  
}
```

Input ->

1

With the above code it gets terminated without taking the string input.

IF I CHANGE THE LINE (a) with 
**cin>>str** the code runs fine

I/p 
1

hello

O/p

hello

the loops runs **t** time but if the line (a) is **getline(cin,str)** the loop run **t-1** times.

Can someone explain the problem why is this happening?

Comment: Also note: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Thanks alot I learnt two things 
one is cin.ignore() for a newline character

And why not to use bits/stdc++.h